# Cesàro operator is bounded for $1<p<\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

The Cesàro operator $T\colon \ell_{p}\to\ell_{p}$ is defined by $(Tx)_{k}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_{j},\: k\in\mathbb{N}$,
where $x=(x_{k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ Show that $T$ is bounded if $1<p<\infty$.
I can do it for $p=\infty$, but not when it is between $1$ and $\infty$.
Thank you.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, note that you can also directly apply the [Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcinkiewicz_interpolation_theorem) for $\mathbb{N}$ with the counting measure.

Comment: @WillieWong Could you please give some more detail on how are going to apply MI?

Comment: @AD. $T$ is bounded $\ell_1 \to \ell_1^w$ and $\ell_\infty\to\ell_\infty$. So by MI it is bounded $\ell_p\to\ell_p$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [Hardy inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality) one may see that
$$
\Vert T(x)\Vert_p=
\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left|\frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{j=1}^k x_j\right|^p\right)^{1/p}\leq
\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{j=1}^k |x_j|\right)^p\right)^{1/p}\leq
$$
$$
\left(\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^p\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty |x_j|^p\right)^{1/p}=
\frac{p}{p-1}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty |x_j|^p\right)^{1/p}=
\frac{p}{p-1}\Vert x\Vert_p
$$
This means that
$$
\Vert T\Vert\leq\frac{p}{p-1}
$$

Answer (score 6):

Some hints:
let $q$ the conjugate exponent of $p$: $1/p+1/q=1$. Write
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^Nx_k\right|^p=\left|\sum_{k=1}^Nx_kk^{1/(pq)}k^{-1/(pq)}\right|^p$$
and use Hölder's inequality to get that
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^Nx_k\right|^p\leq \sum_{k=1}^N\left|x_k\right|^pk^{1/q}N^{p/q-1q}$$
(we have to find a bound for $\sum_{k=1}^N k^{-1/(pq)}$ for example comparing with an integral).
Then take the sum over $N$, change the order of summation and find a bound, comparing with an integral, of $\sum_{N\geq k}N^{-1-1/q}$ to get the result.

In fact, we used [Hardy's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44456/various-proofs-of-hardys-inequality).

Note that for $p=1$ (even if it's not asked), $T$ is not well-defined since if we take $x:=(1,0,\ldots,0,\ldots)$ then $(Tx)_k=\frac 1k$ so $x\notin \ell^1$.

Comment: Why didn't you just apply Hardy's inequality?

Comment: I just wanted to give the steps which lead to this inequality. I didn't read the proof of the link in details, so I don't know whether this approach is different or not.

Comment: Okey, now I see what you mean! Btw, it would be much more interesting to put on a weight in the norm.