# convergence of a sequence based on comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

If the sequence $b_n$ is defined as $$b_n =\frac {a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}n.$$

then[image]

I found out that $b_n$ is always divergent and now that I have to prove the given statement I tried using comparison test. The problem is that I am getting that this is true if the sequence $a_n$ in monotonically increasing. But the hypothesis only says that it is a non negative sequence.

Comment: DO you want to show that if $\sum a_n^2$ converges, then so is $\sum b_n^2$?

Comment: yes John, i want to show the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a special case of [Hardy's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44456/various-proofs-of-hardys-inequality). Also, you probably meant "monotonically decreasing" instead of "increasing"; (obviously an increasing sequence of positive numbers does not converge to zero, and in particular is not square summable.) If you do have a proof for any decreasing positive sequence $a_n$, then you can easily reduce the general case to that case: let $a_n^{*}$ be the non-increasing rearrangement of $a_n$. Then $b_n^*\geq b_n$ but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n^{*})^2$, so it is sufficient to deal with a non-increasing sequence. You may find [this paper](http://www.um.es/functanalysis/meetingsold/Zafra/III_Escuela_AF_files/The%20Prehistory%20of%20the%20Hardy%20Inequality.pdf) interesting, too.